# Overriden Virtual Function not called

Tags: c++

I have a struct object that has several virtual functions

object.h

```
struct object {
public:
    ...
    virtual float intersect(Point, Vector, object*, Point*);
    virtual Vector normal(Point, object*);
};
```

and they are implemented in another struct called sphere

sphere.h

```
struct sphere: public object {
        ...
        // intersect ray with sphere
        float intersect(Point, Vector, object*, Point*) override;
        // return the unit normal at a point on sphere
        Vector normal(Point, object*) override;
    };
```

I and create and store pointers to spheres in a vector via

```
extern vector<object*> scene;
sphere *new_sphere;
new_sphere = (sphere *) malloc(sizeof(sphere));
...
scene.push_back(new_sphere);
```

So the problem happens when I try calling intersect with the following code

```
extern std::vector<object*> scene;
...
object *intersect_scene(Point p, Vector u, Point *intersect, int ignore) {
    for (vector<object*>::iterator it = scene.begin(); it != scene.end(); ++it) {
            float intersect_point = (*it)->intersect(p, u, *it, &temp_hit);
    }
```

I get the following error from gdb

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004042ef in intersect_scene (p=..., u=..., intersect=0x7fffffffdcd0, 
    ignore=-1) at trace.cpp:70
70          float intersect_point = (*it)->intersect(p, u, *it, &temp_hit);
```

Can someone give me some insight as to what's going on here?

by request:

```
struct Point{
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
};

struct Vector{
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
};
```

Comment: `Can someone give me some insight as to what's going on here?`  We don't know where, when, and how this code is being called, we don't know the state of any of those variables you're calling, etc.  Needless to say, you need to isolate the problem and come up with a full example that shows the error.  Since you're using pointers and dynamically allocated memory, the obvious reason is due to memory/pointer mismanagement somewhere in your application.

Comment: What is `Point`?  What is `Vector`?  You're passing these by value (at least that is what that code suggests).  This means that they better have working copy constructors that perform correct copies.

Comment: Point and Vectors are two structs. I was hoping it would be something as simple as your iterator is incorrect

Comment: How about posting these structs?

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted looks suspicious.  The problem is more than likely the code you didn't post, and the error is where the program finally breaks down.

Comment: So it's nothing to do with passing around `extern std::vector<object*> scene`?

Comment: Where do you allocate memory for this:  `sphere *new_sphere;...scene.push_back(new_sphere);`  Those dots are hiding important information.  Without any further code, you are pushing back an uninitialized pointer.  And BTW, your base class `object` needs a virtual destructor.

Comment: Added the requested information

Comment: Argghh!! malloc()!!  Why??

Comment: Conclusion -- pretend that `malloc` doesn't exist when writing a C++ program.  Only if you know *exactly* what you're doing should you even attempt a call to `malloc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `malloc` to construct non-POD objects.  Use `new` instead.

All `malloc` does is allocate bytes -- it does *not* construct objects.  Your `sphere` object has virtual functions, is derived from a base class, etc.  These types must be properly constructed, and malloc doesn't do the job.

In addition, if you have calls to `free()`, they must also be changed to call `delete`.

The only time to use `malloc` in terms of object construction is if you're using `placement-new`, which your code is not doing.

Comment: So I should use `new_sphere = new sphere`?

Comment: Yes, use `new` (even though that may have design issues, but that's another story).  Using `malloc` was definitely wrong.